# Why is an empty result an error? ( $wpdb->get_row )

Tags: wpdb, get-row

I have a query where I get the highest id from a table.

```
$user_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM $table)")
```

The table should always have rows, but if for some reason it returns empty, there is an error (printed with `$wpdb->print_error()`):

```
WordPress database error: []
```

I was wondering why an empty result means an error? And how would I prevent this error?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe there´s another/a better way to do what you want...

Comment: Is this sub-query faster than ordering by ID with a LIMIT 0,1 ? What's the generated SQL query?

Comment: I get what I want with the query - I get the row with the highest id (the latest one). So it will always work. I just wanted to eliminate the possibility of errors, and if the the table is empty, the query returns 0 results, which is an error. I don't understand why it is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an error. The square brackets are empty-- aka "no error". Put a spurious comma in the SQL and you will see what I mean.

But your SQL is wildly complicated for you are doing. That is entirely equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Though, I notice you are using `id` rather than `ID` and I don't remember any Core tables using the lowercase version. If this is meant for a Core table that will be a problem.

Comment: Alright, great info! I use it for a custom table that I made. If there is no error, does it mean that $wpdb->print_error() will always display "WordPress database error" even when there is no error? That SQL statement looks nice, I didn't think about DESC LIMIT!